# Azure App Service Linux didn't respond to HTTP ping on port

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to run my own container in App Service Linux. It's an image that is based from `otel\opentelemetry-collector-contrib` image, the only difference is I changed the application's config inside it to allow CORS.

I know the image has no problem because I've been running it locally in Docker without problem. When deploying to Azure App Service Linux, I got the error about `Container 0 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080`

When running locally, all I need to do is `docker run -p 4318:4318 myname\myimagename`. So in Azure, I set the Startup Command to `-p 4318:4318` and Settings of `WEBSITES_PORT` to 4318. But I'm still getting the error.

I don't think the image has any problem, I've been running it locally without problems. If it's broken, it should be that I'm missing some configuration setting. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the setting you placed in the startup command and try again.

Comment: Wow, that works! I don't know how or why that works though...